# Is it possible to adjust the sizes of square and circle inside a unit circle so the combined area is half of that unit circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]A square and a circle fits together inside an unit circle symmetrically. Is it possible to adjust the sizes of circle and the square so that their combined area is half of the area of that unit circle ?

I tried it like this : As the circle is of unit radius so radius is equal to 1 and so its area is irrational. Now let the length of the square be $a$ and that radius of circle be $r$  and now the question becomes is it possible such that $a^2$+$πr^2$ = $π/2$ since the combined area is half of the unit circle. There I got stuck as RHS is irrational . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: let $x$ be the distance between the center of the big circle and the intersection point of the square with the small circle. Do you see why $x+2r=1$ and $(\frac a2)^2+(a-x)^2=1$? Can you use those equations to reduce the problem to a problem in one unknown?

Answer (score 1):

**Trying to Proving the Existence ( Answering the Question in the title ) :**

Where-ever we take the Centre $X$ of the Inner Circle , we can get the Combined total Area by Drawing the Square beside it.
We can move the Point $X$ from right Extreme to left Extreme.

In the Image , we can Draw the largest Square ( Blue ) inside the Circle & then Draw the Small Circle ( Blue ) beside it. Here $X$ is right Extreme.

Area of outer Circle is $\pi \approx 3.14$

Here , the Combined Blue total Area is more than half the outer Circle.
Diagonal of Square is $2$ , Area is $2$ , Combined Area will be a little more than $2$.

Now , the Purple Circle can be almost the whole Outer Circle, with a very small Purple Square. Here $X$ is left Extreme.

Hence , Combined Purple total Area is more than half the outer Circle.

[image: I1]

Combined Area varies continuously from more than half to some minimum to more than half. Is there a Point $X$ where Combined Area is Exactly half ?

If YES , Where is that Point $X$ ?
We can figure that out by making a Equation.
Let the Inner Circle have Diameter $x$ , & the Square have Side $y$.
Combined Area is $ y^2 + \pi x^2 / 4 = \pi / 2 $ [[ EQ1 ]]

[image: I2]

The left most Part $ z = 1 - \sqrt {1-y^2/4} $

Hence the Outer Circle Diameter is $ 2 = x+y+z $
$ 2 = x + y + 1 - \sqrt {1-y^2/4} $
$ x+y-1 = \sqrt {1-y^2/4} $
$ (x+y-1)^2 = 1-y^2/4 $ [[ EQ2 ]]

**Solving  [[ EQ1 ]] &  [[ EQ2 ]] will give the necessary Point $X$.

Value will be cumbersome , involving square root , $\pi$ , square , Etc.**

$ y^2 + \pi x^2 / 4 = \pi / 2 $
$ (x+y-1)^2 = 1-y^2/4 $
$ y^2 = \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 $
$ y = \sqrt { \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 } $

$ (x+\sqrt { \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 }-1)^2 = 1-\sqrt { ( \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 ) }^2/4 $
$ (x+\sqrt { \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 }-1)^2 = 1- ( \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 )/4 $
$ (x-1)^2+ ( \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 ) + 2(x-1)\sqrt { \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 } = 1- ( \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 )/4 $
$ 2(x-1)\sqrt { \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 } =  -(x-1)^2 - ( \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 ) + 1- ( \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 )/4 $
$ 4(x-1)^2 ( \pi / 2 - \pi x^2 / 4 ) = [ -(x-1)^2 - \pi / 2 + \pi x^2 / 4 + 1 - \pi / 8 + \pi x^2 / 16 ] ^2 $

We can use [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4%28x-1%29%5E2%20%28%20%5Cpi%20%2F%202%20-%20%5Cpi%20x%5E2%20%2F%204%20%29%20%3D%20%5B%20-%28x-1%29%5E2%20-%20%5Cpi%20%2F%202%20%2B%20%5Cpi%20x%5E2%20%2F%204%20%2B%201%20-%20%5Cpi%20%2F%208%20%2B%20%5Cpi%20x%5E2%20%2F%2016%20%5D%20%5E2) to get the answer $x ≈ 0.995126$ & hence $y ≈ 0.890525$ . We can then verify this :
Combined Area is $ 0.890525^2 + \pi 0.995126 / 4  = 1.57460...$ which is quite close to half the Outer Circle Area.

Comment: The area of the unit circle is just $\pi$ and $2 > \pi/2,$ so both of your "extreme" cases have area greater than half the outer circle. But there is a minimum in between these two cases.

Comment: I have updated the answer , thanks for the Pointer  , @DavidK

Comment: I have updated that Point , thank you , @nickgard , hope no other "simple bloopers" !!!

Comment: @Prem , I think the equation $[[EQ1]]$  must be $y^2+πx^2/4 = π/2$. There is a mistake in $[[EQ1]]$ I think.

Comment: @Prem , I think in the last statement it will '' Solving $[[EQ1]]$ and $[[EQ2]]$'' instead of ''Solving $[[EQ2]]$ and $[[EQ2]]$'' . A writing mistake I think.

Comment: And can you please elaborate your solution of how you found point $X$ after solving $[[EQ1]]$ and $[[EQ2]]$.

Comment: I have updated the corrections , thank you , @Adam100 , I will try solving it tomorrow.

Comment: An intersection of two conics? That's equivalent to solving some polynomial of degree 4.

Comment: There were Square terms & Square root terms hence we will eventually get a Degree 4 Polynomial , which will be even more cumbersome due to $\pi$ here & there ! @IvanNeretin

Comment: I have added the Solution now , @Adam100 , hope it is useful !!

Comment: The last equation squares both sides of the previous line. Evaluating that penultimate line at $x\approx0.995126$ gives the LHS as negative and the RHS as positive, but with the same absolute value (about $0.0087$). A false solution has been introduced by squaring. The penultimate line doesn't have a positive real solution for $x$. $EQ1$ is implicitly seeking the value for $x$ where the combined area of the square and small circle is $\pi/2$, but I think there is no such value.

Comment: What you observed could be true , that is why I tried to "verify" the Wolfram Solution , where I did get somewhere close to the half ratio , @nickgard [[ My own Concern/Problem with this Solution is : We have Area more than half at Extremes & somewhere Area is minimum , then Either (1) minimum is less than half & there must be at least  2 Cases where Area is Exactly half , yet we got Single Solution Or (2) minimum is more than half & Area is never half Or (3) minimum is Exactly half , which is very unlikely. Currently , I do not have to the tools to Plot that Curve to check the minimum. ]]